# BasicDataSource cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

Hi I am using spring based web application in my project i tried to add dependency
in pom.xml for dcbp 1.2 but its still showing me error above error

please help me how i can resolve it
I tried following ways:
Add depedency dbcp 1,2
apache tomcat inbuild lib dbcp 
mvn clean update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the version of dcbp 
Add this to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```